# how to adjust % if we remove one value from the list

Tags: algorithm, math, mean

Lets suppose we have 4 section of item and % of each section is

A= 25,B =25,C=25, D=25                that make it 100% item

Lets suppose we take we take C

now

A = 33.3, B =33.3 , C= 33.3   right

but lets suppose we have

A= 10,B =20 ,C=20, D=20 , E = 30                  that make it 100% item

and now we take C out then what will be value of

A= ?,B =? , D=?, E = ?

and how can we program it

Comment: By multiplying each remaining item with 100 / (100 − C)?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you have 100 items. So you have:

A=10 (10%), B=20 (20%), C=20 (20%), D=20 (20%), E=30 (30%). Total is 100 items, 100%.

Now, you remove 30 items. So now you have:

A=10, B=20, C=30, D=20, for a total of 70 items. Divide each sum by the total to get the percentage.

- A=10/70 = 14.29%
- B=20/70 = 28.57%
- C=20/70 = 28.57%
- D=20/70 = 28.57%
- Total: 70 items, 100%